# Files open in the current session

Tags: bash

I need to count the open files for the active processes in the current session. But Only regular files. I don´t know how to "mix" the ps command with the lsof command.
Lsof doesn´t return which processes belong to the current session. And when i use ps to list the active processes, i dont know how to save the pids to look it for with the lsof command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a comma-separated list of pids to `lsof` using [command substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html) as follows:

```
lsof -p $(ps -o pid= | tr '\n' ',')
```

Answer (score 0):

use the environment variable for the pid of your current process (and its parent): $$(,$PPID)

```
lsof -R -p $$,$PPID
```

the -R tells lsof to print the PPID column